# How to @Find for <list>webelement?

Tags: java, selenium

When you declare one webelement in the page object, you can do something like:

```
@FindBy(name="q") private WebElement searchBox;
```

How do declare for multiple Elements? The following doesn't work:

```
@FindBys(class="li") private <List>WebElement searchBoxes;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "doesn't work"? Is there a compile error? Cause `@FindBys` doesn't exist or might just be a typo from your side. Or does it not find the element. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was mistaken. It is possible to do:
@FindBy(name="q") private List searchBoxes;

Comment: @FindBy(class="li") private List <WebElement> searchBoxes;